# How to call a function from one script attached to a game object to another in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically I have one script set up which during play prints to the console.

```
//Method to loop find question to be asked and print it as well as loop through answerText and print the appropriate answer options/
public void AskNewQuestion ()
{
    //prints Person: + apropriate question based on questionUpTo.
    Debug.Log ("Person:" + questionsText [questionUpTo]);
    //Loops through answersText and compares it to questionUpTo to find applicable answers.
    for (int i = 0; i < answerText[questionUpTo].Count; i++) 
    {
        //Prints applicable answers to console.
        Debug.Log(i+1 + ":" + answerText[questionUpTo][i]);
    }
}
```

Now I need this to print not to the console, but through another script which handles a canvas, and the canvas is where I need the text to print to.

```
public class Textboxmanager : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject textBox;

    public Text theText;

    public TextAsset textFile;
    public string[] textLines;

    public int currentLine;
    public int endAtLine;

    public bool isActive;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        if(textFile != null)
        {
            textLines = (textFile.text.Split('\n'));
        }

        if(endAtLine == 0)
        {
            endAtLine = textLines.Length - 1;
        }

        if(isActive)
        {
            EnableTextBox();
        }
        else
        {
            DisableTextBox();
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(!isActive)
        {
            return;
        }

        theText.text = textLines[currentLine];

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            currentLine += 1;
        }

        if(currentLine > endAtLine)
        {
            DisableTextBox();
        }
    }

    public void EnableTextBox()
    {
        textBox.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void DisableTextBox()
    {
        textBox.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways in which you can accomplish this. First of all, i notice that the script from which you are trying to print to is a manager of sorts. In that case there is a high level concept called Singletons.

Here is a link on how to implement Singletons in C-Sharp:
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-roguelike-tutorial/writing-game-manager

Watch the unity video on them and make sure this is the right approach to your problem.

If you don't want to go down that complex path and would rather avoid the headache then i will try and explain how to reference another script and all of its functions, variables and other data without singletons.

```
Class1 {
    public Class2 class2Reference;

    private void printTextFromClass2() {
        class2Reference.printAnswerText();
    }
}

Class2 {
    public void printAnswerText() {
        Debug.Log("String");
    }
}
```

In this example you can see that i have two classes, these may be in different scripts and on completely different gameObjects within Unity. We created a variable with the datatype as the class name we are trying to access. In this case the datatype is Class2. We then use it as a variable any time that we need to access that script.

The only thing that you must do is give it a script to reference. Much like a string is null until we give it a value, our variable 'private Class2 class2Reference' is null until we give it a value.

This is the easy part. Save and go back to unity. You should see your variable in the inspector with "none" written next to it. Drag and drop your second script into that box and you should be ready to rumble.

Hope this helps you out buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate the AskNewQuestion class inside the TextboxManager class.

```html
puclic TextboxManager : Monobehavior {
  AskNewQuestion askNewQuestion = new AskNewQuestion();
}
```

Make a function inside AskNewQuestion that returns the array string. Then call it on the TextboxManager class to get the array string. Like this: `textLines = askNewQuestion.questions;`.

Edit: You can use a `{ get; set; }` method with this. First initialize on where you store the string array then apply it on the `{ get; set; }` method.

```html
string[] questions;

public string[] Questions {
  get {
    return quesions;
  }
}
```